# How to fix error for return in boolean method

Tags: java, methods, boolean

I'm creating a program that asks a user for a guess number. The program then determines if the guessed number is within the range of two random numbers. I have a public static boolean that shows an error even though I have a return (within a if and else if). New to methods and uncertain how to resolve, how can I fix this? Heads up I cannot create a second boolean, both validations have to remain in displayGuessResults as that is what is required of the program. Also the code is not complete as I haven't gotten through calling in main, I just wanted to resolve this before continuing, thank you!

Code (not including main because I have nothing in it yet):

```
public static int getValidGuess(Scanner get)
    {
       int num;

        System.out.print("Guess a number: --> ");
        num = get.nextInt();

        return num;
    } // getValidGuess end

    public static boolean displayGuessResults(int start, int end, int num)
    {
         int n1, n2;
         Random gen = new Random();

        n1 = gen.nextInt(99) + 1;
        n2 = gen.nextInt(99) + 1;



        if(n1 < n2)
        {
            start = n1;
            end = n2;
        } // if end
        else
        {
            start = n2;
            end = n1;
        } //else end

        if(num > start && num < end)
        {
            System.out.println("\nThe 2 random numbers are " + start +
                    " and " + end);
            System.out.println("Good Guess!");

            return true;
        }
        else if (num < start || num > end)
        {
            System.out.println("\nThe 2 random numbers are " + start +
                    " and " + end);
            System.out.println("Outside range.");

            return false;
        }


    } // displayGuessResults end
```

Comment: "that shows an error" .. can you be more specific about that?

Comment: You don't provide a return statement for each possible scenario. if both your if and else if return false, there needs to be a return statement for that as well.

Comment: You need to add true/false outside if/else block also. Before displayGuessResults end.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `return` statement at the end of the method,

```
public static boolean displayGuessResults(int start, int end, int num)
    {
         int n1, n2;
         Random gen = new Random();

        n1 = gen.nextInt(99) + 1;
        n2 = gen.nextInt(99) + 1;



        if(n1 < n2)
        {
            start = n1;
            end = n2;
        } // if end
        else
        {
            start = n2;
            end = n1;
        } //else end

        if(num > start && num < end)
        {
            System.out.println("\nThe 2 random numbers are " + start +
                    " and " + end);
            System.out.println("Good Guess!");

            return true;
        }
        else if (num < start || num > end)
        {
            System.out.println("\nThe 2 random numbers are " + start +
                    " and " + end);
            System.out.println("Outside range.");

        }

       return false;
    }
```

Comment: considering the code, it would be easier to just have the if and after that, instead of an else if- > return false

Comment: OP is logging some info in else-if. updated the answer, as return false in else-if is not required.

Comment: yes, but considering the way of logging, it's doubtful in a large(r) application, it will be read.

Answer (score 0):

What if the num == start || num == end ? you haven't considered it, hence for that case it wouldn't enter in either if /else if. and therefore you need to handle it as well